# Edit data in gridview row using Rowupdating event in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

My gridview is based on  sqldatasource. When I Filter the data using dropdown selectedIndexChanged event the gridview shall load data based on what is searched. I need to do the updating operation on what row is clicked.

```
<div class="GridviewPanelBody">
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdTenantUpdate" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
                         BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical"  AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="tenantcode" 
                        Font-Size="Small" width="100%" OnRowDataBound="grdTenantUpdate_RowDataBound" OnRowCancelingEdit="grdTenantUpdate_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="grdTenantUpdate_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="grdTenantUpdate_RowUpdating"   >

                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="tenantcode" HeaderText="Retail Partner Code" SortExpression="tenantcode" ReadOnly="true"  />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Retail Partner" SortExpression="name" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="fixedrate" HeaderText="Fixed Rate" SortExpression="fixedrate"  /> <%--DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00;(#,##0.00);0}"--%>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="percentrate" HeaderText="Percent Rate" SortExpression="percentrate" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="percentage" HeaderText="Percentage %" SortExpression="percentage" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="locationd" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="locationd" ReadOnly="true" />
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#90FF90" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black"  />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
                    </asp:GridView>


                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT a.tenantcode, a.name, a.fixedrate, a.percentrate, a.percentage, b.locationd, c.status FROM TENANTNEW AS a INNER JOIN LOCATION AS b ON a.LOCATION = b.location INNER JOIN TENANT AS c ON a.tenantcode = c.tenantcode WHERE (c.status &gt; 1) ORDER BY b.location, a.name"  
                         UpdateCommand="UPDATE [TENANTNEW] set fixedrate = @fixedrate, percentrate = @percentrate, percentage = @percentage WHERE tenantcode = @tenantcode" OnSelected="SqlDataSource1_Selected"  >

                        <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="fixedrate" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="percentrate" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="percentage" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="tenantcode" />

                        </UpdateParameters>



                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

code behind. I used the following event in the gridview, the only problem is the rowupdating event. How can I successfully update a selected row in the gridview

```
  private void BindData()
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = Session["GridviewData"].ToString();

    }

    protected void grdTenantUpdate_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the edit index.
        grdTenantUpdate.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindData();
    }




    protected void grdTenantUpdate_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //Reset the edit index.
        grdTenantUpdate.EditIndex = -1;
        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindData();
    }


    protected void grdTenantUpdate_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdTenantUpdate.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    Label   tcode = (Label)row.FindControl("tenantcode");
    TextBox tname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("fixedrate");
   // TextBox tques = (TextBox)row.FindControl("que");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update TENANTNEW set fixedrate=@name where id = @id", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar  ).Value = tcode;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Float).Value = tname;
  //  cmd.Parameters.Add("@ques", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = tques.Text.Trim();

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    grdTenantUpdate.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
    }
}
```

ERROR:

The parameterized query '(@id varchar(8000),@name float)update TENANTNEW set fixedrate=@n' expects the parameter '@id', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Hello brother you have to pass `0`  instead of `e.RowIndex` as a index in `DataKeys` so use below code

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(grdTenantUpdate.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString());
```

instead of

```
int id = Int32.Parse(grdTenantUpdate.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

see  [Deference between `Int32.Parse` and `Convert.ToInt32`](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2010/11/difference-between-intparse-and.html)

Comment: Ive tried this, but it did not work, I think Karen is correct my tenantcode is not an int (number) it is a string, What could be the alternative code for that?

Comment: @ricky you may also use HIddenfield and set its value like `Value='<%# Eval("TENANTCODE") %>'` in Item Template field Inside Template field of gridview  and find that control in its RowUpdating Event of Gridview control...

Answer (score 0):

tenantcode - is not a number value

Comment: Yes, you are correct tenantcode is a string, what can I do to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

On Html side - DataKeyNames="tenantcode,id"

On server side :

```
int id;   
Int32.TryParse(grdTenantUpdate.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString(), out id);
```